What is the formula to prevent cell from being over written when reference cell is updated?
Information on sheet 1 is automatically updated from a database on a once daily schedule.
Cells on sheet 2 use a vlookup function that points to data on sheet 1. The formulas populate sheet 2 cells A2:Y2
If I mark sheet 2, cell A1 with ‘Yes’ or “z”, I want cells A2:Y2 to remain constant for as long as I have them marked ‘Yes’ or ‘z’, even when sheet 1 does its daily update and while cells A3:Y3 continue to change.
I tried a few IF functions but not having any luck

How is the daily update managed? Is that a query? You may be able to include your results as an argument to the query. A formula is designed to calculate. If a linked cell is updated, the formula is triggered to recalculate. So either look into the start of my comment, or look into a VBA solution.

Could you just duplicate the worksheet into a Sheet 3 before the data refresh? Then you can update your formulas to say =IF(OR(A1="Yes",A1="z"), ...then use Sheet 3, ...else use Sheet 1). And then you can keep that second copy of the data as up to date (or as outdated) as you'd like.

P.b  I don’t have unlimited access to the sheet one data.  They can give me the data I need, but the manipulation has to occur on the side I work on.  I think what you are talking about would involve my sheet making direct query to the bigger data base.

Jacob K.  This sounds like it is a good possibility!  I’ll have to give it a try.
